# Htaccess Redirect To Other Url With Same Query String

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i have a big problem with redirect. I'm trying to redirect

```
www.site.com/article?var=1&var=2
```

To

```
www.redirecturl.com/tid=id&var=1&var=2
```

so i need only to make a redirect passing variable to my new redirect url. How can i do it?

I already tryed with some solutions found on stack but does not works.

Thanks for help.

**UPDATE**
I tryed with this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^/article?$" www.redirecturl.com/?tid=trackingid
```

Redirect work, but don't append any query string from old url :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `RedirectMatch` directive, you should use `mod_rewrite` rule with `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^article/?$ http://www.redirecturl.com/?tid=trackingid [L,NC,R=301,QSA]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Comment: Thanks a lot @anubhava ! Works!